# How to urlencode UTC datetime strings?

Tags: python-3.x, http, datetime, python-requests, urllib

I am using python's urllib.parse.urlencode to encode a request body to make a 'get' request for a url. I am running into trouble when encoding a UTC datetime string.

The endpoints expects the date to look like: 
`begin=2004-01-01T00:00:00&end=2019-04-21T00:00:00`

but after using urlencode, the date payload looks like: 
`begin=2020-02-04T17%3A00%3A00&end=2020-02-04T20%3A00%3A00`

The format of the first half of the UTC datetime looks okay, (YYYY-MM-DDT), but second half is screwed up. It SHOULD look like `T00:00:00` but does not.

I am passing a dictionary of parameters into the urlencode function:

`params = {
        'begin':'2020-02-04T17:00:00',
        'end':'2020-02-04T20:00:00',
}
return urlencode(params, doseq=True)`

How can I encode the date in the correct format? Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help you all. Thank you.

Comment: URL encoding is **supposed to do exactly that**, [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: hmm....so then if the request needs the date in a specific format that is NOT percent encoded, how do I "paste" the datestring into the request body ?

Comment: Where are these parameters going? GET's don't have a 'body', and params _in the query portion_ of a URL are required to be urlencoded. POST's do have a body which can have several formats, _one_ of which is urlencoded but many others aren't, and they are all different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%3A` is `:` when urlencoded.

Hence `begin=2020-02-04T17:00:00&end=2020-02-04T20:00:00` when encoded will be `begin=2020-02-04T17%3A00%3A00&end=2020-02-04T20%3A00%3A00`, as stated in your question.

The format is correct and there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: hmm I see. I guess I just need to build a custom payload formatter.